# SQL. Select names of users who have certain set of skills

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

There are **three** tables:

[image]

**Skills** table has the following data:

[image]

I need to select names of users, who are skilled in **BOTH** *Node.js* **AND** *JavaScript*.

So basically I need to select ids of two skills and then filter Users by those skills.

Unfortunately I couldn't come up with a query.

Answer (score 0):

You can use exists in a query:

```
with Skilled (UserId) as
(
  select UserId
  from 
  (select distinct us.UserId, us.SkillId 
    from UserSkills us 
    inner join Skills s on us.SkillId = s.Id 
    where s.Name in ('Node.js', 'Javascript')) tmp
  group by UserId
  having count(*) = 2 
)
select Id, Name 
from Users u
where exists (select * from Skilled s where s.userId = u.Id);
```

[DBFiddle demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2019&fiddle=d89067144d19e11cf71cb18f4f558258)

Answer (score -1):

```
;with E1 as
(
select us.UserId
from UserSkills us
where SkillId in (1, 2)
group by UserId
having count(*) = 2;
)
SELECT Name FROM User AS us
LEFT JOIN E1 AS e ON e.UserId=us.UserId
```

THATS IT

Comment: That is not it. Assuming typos corrected, this would return anyone including those with no skills.